# 'pip install causallift' does not install

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

I want to install the Python package causallift, but the installation lingers at 'Installing build dependencies...'.

When I install with:

```
pip3 install causallift
```

The installation stays at 'Installing build dependencies' for hours.

Comment: Run `pip3 install causallift -vvv` and paste the log captured once the build starts to hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try 2 more options:

1. run: `pip3 install git+https://github.com/Minyus/causallift.git`
2. clone the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Minyus/causallift), cd into the downloaded repository, and run: `python setup.py install`